# How can I give all users access to a read-only ‘sample’ in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on fairly standard Ruby on Rails app where `users` have many `studies`. When a user signs up, I would like them to have a sample `study` as an example, similar to how Trello gives you a sample board on sign up.

My current approach is to `deep_clone` `Study.first` on registration and assign ownership to the current user. This means new users can edit their clone of the sample study and no-one else can see their changes. This works fairly well however it has now become quite complicated to clone studies as my associations are a lot more complex.

To simplify, I would like to change my approach for the sample study. Instead of cloning, I now want to give everyone *access* to the first study in the database, but read-only. Studies have a few views, e.g. users can change questions, participants, settings, add tags, etc. They should be able to *see* existing questions, participants, settings, and tags, but not add, remove, or edit them for this sample study.

I believe I need to:

- Figure out how to make `Study.first` show up for everyone in all the right views without it actually being owned by `current_user`
- Make this study read-only for everyone except me

What's a good approach for doing this in Rails?

Comment: How about storing the data for this sample study in a global 'setting' object that you or an administrator can control, and then just create that study for each new user? you could let them edit that study if it's basically trash. That assumes each trash 'study' doesn't occupy a ton of db space.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the study is actually pretty large so it's fairly expensive to create one for every user that signs up.

Answer (score 0):

For a **classical server side application** there are few ways around that you would need to use some sort of persistence to store the users changes between requests.

You could possibly setup some sort of inheritance so that studies can inherit from another study and use delegation to avoid duplication.

```
class Study
  belongs_to :master, class: 'Study', optional: true

  def get_some_field
    master ? master.get_some_field : super
  end
end
```

If the user is manipulating questions, participants, settings, and tags they should merely be working on join tables which are pretty cheap since they only involve storing two integers per row.

Another solution could be storing diffs or just the actual changes the user performs. It might be possible to use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) or at least study it as a starting point.

For an **ajax heavy application** or **SPA** you might want to use local storage to fake the whole server interaction.

When a user creates a demo study they would fetch `/studies/1.json` and then when the play around they are just manipulating the object stored on the client.

In Ember you could for example swap out the adapter to `ember-localstorage-adapter`.